# managing sensitive settings and configuration files across servers and development environments

Tags: git, version-control, configuration, ansible, devops

What do medium sized companies use for managing sensitive settings and configuration files across servers and development environment? I work with a small team of developers, and a decent pool of servers. Using a configuration management tool like Ansible seems to have run its course, as it's just not very efficient when releasing code multiple times per day. Far too often are developers waiting for someone to push settings and configuration changes to the servers via Ansible before they can release code. Instead, I would think keeping the files encrypted somewhere and having them loaded as part of the deploy process would be a better option. Is this standard procedure? Any advice or experience would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You should use [Ansible Vault](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_vault.html) for this. To decrypt, you can share a password, or as i do a password file. So your passwords etc can stay in git, but they are encrypted.

Comment: I do use ansible vault for this, but even with that, the workflow seems clunky and slow...

Comment: you keep talking about Ansible being slow. I wonder if you're using it wrong.

Comment: @tedder I don't think Ansible is slow, but the process of having a developer send over new configs to the designated Ansible person (who may or may not be available when the developer needs the changes pushed), updating the templates for the configuration files, opening the encrypted files where the settings are kept (3x on this one due to three environments), then running the playbook first against a staging group, then the production group does take a while

Comment: aha- that's a Conway problem, not an Ansible problem.

Comment: I think it is a process problem. When you need more speed in staging you should think about CI and CD.

Comment: @el_wichtel, where could you see CI/CD being used there?